# Struct Variable = {0} Notation

Tags: c++

I'm looking at the windows socket API and it uses:

```
WSADATA wsaData = {0};
```

What exactly does this {0} do?

Comment: It initializes all the memebers in the struct to 0

Answer (score 4):

It means you are initializing every element inside the struct to 0.

Even if you write

```
WSADATA wsaData = {};
```

then also it will initialize every member of struct to zero.

**On a side note:**

Static storage duration objects are always initialized to zero. From the standard:

> Objects with static storage duration (3.7.1) shall be zero-initialized
>   (8.5) before any other initialization takes place. Zero-initialization
>   and initialization with a constant expression are collectively called
>   static initialization; all other initialization is dynamic
>   initialization. Objects of POD [plain old data] types (3.9) with
>   static storage duration initialized with constant expressions (5.19)
>   shall be initialized before any dynamic initialization takes place.
>   Objects with static storage duration defined in namespace scope in the
>   same translation unit and dynamically initialized shall be initialized
>   in the order in which their definition appears in the translation
>   unit. [Note:8.5.1 describes the order in which aggregate members are
>   initialized. The initial- ization of local static objects is described
>   in 6.7.]

Comment: note that the `{}` requires C++11, where `{0}` also works with older compilers.

Answer (score 2):

```
WSADATA wsaData = {0};
WSADATA wsaData = {}; // This is also allowed, and is the same as the above one
```

means initialise all members in the struct to `0`.

This is also applicable to arrays. Example:

```
int numbers[20] = {0}
```

all elements in the `numbers` array are initialised to `0`

Comment: Thanks. Are you familiar with the windows socket API? Do you know if WSASTARTUP initializes the WSADATA struct? It accepts a reference to it and the API doc doesn't really say.

Comment: @user3735829 I'm sorry but I'm not. You can ask another question to get professional answers. Good Luck

Comment: You can in fact just go `= { };` . Any member that's not mentioned is value-initialized . In C you need to at least mention one member but in C++ you don't.